# ArgoCD can't connect to a github account with 2FA

Tags: kubernetes, digital-ocean, continuous-deployment, circleci

I'm trying to use CircleCI + ArgoCD for CD/CI on a digitalocean kubernetes cluster, is there a way to connect ArgoCD to a github account that have 2FA enabled? Because every time I go in the connect repo section it gives me "Unable to connect repository: authentication required" but the credentials are the correct one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use a access token, check this bloc https://help.github.com/en/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line